# Reverse Geocoding Displaying incorreclty

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to add an address to my infowindow using reverse geocoding.  For some reason my address is being displayed as: addresscom.google.gwt.maps.client.geocoder.GeocoderResult@157d1af and I'm not sure how to get it to display as a string.
 Here is my code.

```
final GeocoderRequest request = new GeocoderRequest();
request.setLatLng(point);   //point is lat long to be displayed
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode(request, new GeocoderCallback() {

    @Override
    public void callback(List<HasGeocoderResult> responses, String status) {
                HasGeocoderResult result = responses.get(0);
                String address = result.toString();


                infoWindow2.setContent(address);        

                infoWindow2.open(myMap.getMap(), marker2);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that the class HasGeocodeResult does not have a specific implementation of the toString method. What you see (GeocoderResult@157d1af) is the output of the standard implementation of toString in the Object class.

A better idea would be to look for other method in GeocoderResult that you can use to create a a human-readable description of the result.

For instance, there seems to be a called getAddressComponents(). I'm sure you can create a decent output from this method (and possible some other methods). I'm not familiar with these classes so I don't really know what those things are, but how about some code like this:

```
StringBuilder address = new StringBuilder();
for (HasAddressComponent component : result.getAddressComponent()) {
    address.append(component.getLongName());
    address.append("\n");
}

infoWindow2.setContent(address.toString);
```